How can I adapt the eurosym package to run in math mode with a comma as decimal separator?
The solution given below by @egreg here package eurosym: how to change the decimal separator? allows you to change the decimal separator to a comma (instead of a period). How can I get this solution to work in math mode too?
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

\sisetup{locale=FR}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[2][]{%
  \if@EURleft\euro\,\fi
  \num[#1]{#2}%
  \if@EURleft\else\,\euro\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Avec un point : \EUR{10.30}%<---  work

Avec une virgule : \EUR{10,30}%<---  work

En mode maths $\EUR{4825}\div100=\dots$%<--- dont work

\[\EUR{4825}\div100=\dots\]%<--- dont work
\end{document}



Yes, I want to, but how do I do it?

Use \mbox{\normalfont\euro}. You don't want surprises about tha shape, do you?
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[2][]{%
  \if@EURleft\mbox{\normalfont\euro}\,\fi
  \num[#1]{#2}%
  \if@EURleft\else\,\mbox{\normalfont\euro}\fi
}
\makeatother

Complete example
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

\sisetup{locale=FR}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\EUR}[2][]{%
  \if@EURleft\mbox{\normalfont\euro}\,\fi
  \num[#1]{#2}%
  \if@EURleft\else\,\mbox{\normalfont\euro}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Avec un point : \EUR{10.30}

Avec une virgule : \EUR{10,30}

En mode maths $\EUR{4825}\div100=\dots$

\textit{En mode maths $\EUR{4825}\div100=\dots$}

\[\EUR{4825}\div100=\dots\]

\end{document}


